How to boot a desired partition of a UEFI disk with Qemu?
I cloned a GPT formatted disk that contains a dual boot (Windows + Linux Debian) that works perfectly well on its real machine.
I try to create a VM with Qemu that uses the cloned disk, to make it boot on the Debian partition but the best I could do is to boot Windows.
Here is the command I used:
virt-install \
    --name "vm-test_dual_boot" \
    --boot loader=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd \
    --vcpus 2 --memory 8192 --osinfo debian11 \
    --network bridge=br0 \
    --graphics=vnc \
    --disk path=/home/user/vm/clone.qcow2 \
    --import -v

I can not do the same thing as the real UEFI machine which associates a HD(1,GPT,unique_identifier) ​​filesystem with the \EFI\debian\shimx64.efi file.
Could you help me boot Debian?

Thanks to @telcoM I changed the command in :
boot_config=\
"loader=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.fd,"\
"loader.readonly=yes,"\
"loader.type=pflash,"\
"nvram.template=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd,"\
"nvram=/home/user/vm/clone_nvram.fd" ;

virt-install \
    --name "vm-test_dual_boot" \
    --boot $boot_config \
    --vcpus 2 --memory 8192 --osinfo win10 \
    --network bridge=br0 \
    --graphics=vnc \
    --disk path=/home/user/vm/clone.qcow2 \
    --import -v

Notes:

from the directory /usr/share/OVMF loader must match the nvram.template then OVMF_CODE_4M.fd to OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd, so in my case this triggered this error : "Guest has not initialized the display ( yet )".

the user defined in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf (default : libvirt-qemu), must have read and execute right acccess to the nvram file else this trigger a permission error.

in my case --osinfo win10 is mandatory as the default vHD EFI boot is Windows (before I tried debian11 which ended on BSOD).

for the --network part it is assumed that we have a br0 bridge device (see here for temporary bridge with Network Manager or here with iproute and here for permanent one with ifup).


Once created, configure VM EFI to boot the right partition (see @telcoM detailed  answer to achieve it temporarily or permanently).

You haven't defined a NVRAM storage for boot variables, so there is no place to persistently store the UEFI boot variables to. As a result, the system will always fall back to booting from \EFI\boot\bootx64.efi... and by default, Windows places its backup bootloader there.
You'll need to do something like:
virt-install \
    --name "vm-test_dual_boot" \
    --boot loader=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd,loader.readonly=yes,loader.type=pflash,nvram.template=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd,nvram=/home/user/vm/clone_nvram.fd \
    --vcpus 2 --memory 8192 --osinfo debian11 \
    --network bridge=br0 --graphics=vnc \
    --disk path=/home/user/vm/clone.qcow2 \
    --import -v

This will reserve a space for UEFI boot settings in the form of a small file located at /home/user/vm/clone_nvram.fd. This file will represent the persistent NVRAM storage on the virtual motherboard.
The dual-boot VM will still boot into Windows on the first time, because the fallback bootloader path still holds the Windows bootloader (and the "self-healing" of modern Windows will probably keep it that way).
The next step is to enter the UEFI firmware boot settings menu of the VM. If you are really fast, you might be able to get there by pressing F2 while the VM is booting up, but an easier way is to tell Windows to reboot and go there in the next boot (from Microsoft):

from either the Sign on screen or the Start menu, select Power (Power button icon) > hold Shift while selecting Restart. Select Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware settings.

Once there, you can go into Boot Maintenance Manager sub-menu, select Boot from File, select your virtual disk, then select the <EFI> folder, then the <debian> sub-folder and then the shimx64.efi file. This will let you boot GRUB, and thus Debian, in the VM.
To create a persistent boot entry for GRUB, use grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda (assuming your system disk is /dev/sda; if your system disk is /dev/vda instead, adjust accordingly) to reinstall the GRUB bootloader and to rewrite the UEFI boot variable for it.
(You could also do it using the efibootmgr command, but using grub-install is probably easier.)
When cloning a non-dualboot Linux system, you could avoid complications like this with UEFI systems (virtual or not) by doing a
grub-install --force-extra-removable

in the original system before cloning it. This will place a second copy of shimx64.efi to /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi, which will effectively make the disk (and its future clones) UEFI-bootable even if the NVRAM settings are lost... or left behind in the original system's UEFI NVRAM chip when cloning systems or converting them to VMs.

Waou ! Really perfect and thank you ;) ! Not only does it work but you also gave me a lot of knowledge that I did not have on the subject. I discovered grub-install does not really install on the vHD. For proof if I destroy the VM and build it again I will have to make the same modifications. Do exist a way (or will be envisaged) to transmit the EFI folder without having to pass from a virtual NVRAM file ? A more direct way...

grub-install writes some *.efi files to the ESP partition of the vHD, but it also writes the NVRAM variables... which will be stored to /home/user/vm/clone_nvram.fd if you followed my recipe. For single-OS VMs the problem can be avoided: Windows already does it for you automatically; for Linux, you'll need to run grub-install --force-extra-removable beforehand to have the same effect. But there can be only one bootloader at /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi, which makes cloning dual-boot disks tricky.

Then no way to transmit the EFI stuff from command line without passing by NVRAM file ? It is maybe conceptually impossible ...

Probably not impossible, but perhaps rarely needed and so not a great priority to implement: unless you're cloning from physical to virtual, there is normally no reason to build a dual-boot VM, as two single-OS VMs are usually more versatile than one dual-boot VM. And with only one OS per VM, you can leave the NVRAM empty and let the virtual firmware default to the fallback path.
